# AWS EventBridge not receiving notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

I have an S3 bucket with EventBridge notifications enabled, let's say it's named "foo"
I also have a rule (in CDK)

```
    Function lambda = Function.Builder.create(this, "Lambda")
            .runtime(Runtime.NODEJS_14_X)
            .handler("index.handler")
            .code(Code.fromInline(source))
            .build();

    EventPattern eventPattern = EventPattern.builder()
            .source(List.of("aws.s3"))
            .detail(Map.of("name", List.of("foo")))
            .detailType(List.of("Object Created"))
            .build();

    Rule rule = Rule.Builder.create(this, "Rule")
            .eventBus(eventBus)
            .eventPattern(eventPattern)
            .build();

    LambdaFunctionProps lambdaFunctionProps = LambdaFunctionProps.builder().build();
    IRuleTarget ruleTarget = new LambdaFunction(lambda, lambdaFunctionProps);
    rule.addTarget(ruleTarget);
```

But I'm not seeing any notifications for a created object. Am I missing anything obvious and where to start looking? BTW which EventBus does the S3 target for notifications?

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

`aws.s3` is AWS owned event bus. You can't use it for your custom events. You have to create your own custom bus instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, looks like I have to read some more. 

I understand that 

a) I can't *send* to an AWS reserved event bus and 
b) the services send to the reserved AWS even bus

but it sounds a bit counterintuitive that I can't make event patterns against the aws.* buses (I mean how are the build-in-AWS-events reacted on at all?)